# How to send email using a Custom Policy Mule 3 when policy violation?

Tags: email, mule, policy, mulesoft

We want to find a solution to send an email when the custom policy is violated using mule 3 , do you have any ideas how to do that ?

i already try this block of code but it didnt worked :

```
<mule:smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" user="testsendmail@gmail.com" password="Aa123456@"  responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"  cc="test1@gmail.Com" from="testsendmail@gmail.com"  to="testsendmail@gmail.com" subject="Test Alert email"  />
```

Comment: what didn't work about it?

Comment: @utechtzs , the whole policy

Comment: I'm still confused. Did it hit the SMTP connector, but you don't receive an email? Did it throw an error? I'm not sure how to help. Sorry.

Comment: @utechtzs , it's a custom policy , not an ordinary mule application, any way thanks for your comments